Error Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
Me da este error al usar phpMailer
mi archivo .env esta asi
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=xxxxxx.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=sxxxx@xxxxw.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="dasdh#juejshg" //ejemplo entre comillas por que la contraseña contiene un #
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxx@xxxxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="XXX"

mi archivo mail.php
'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'autentication' =>'plain',
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

No se si pueda haber conflicto la forma que se esta pasando MAIL_PASSWORD en el .env
